Has Giaquinto been refuted?
In his influential article (cited by almost 50 publications)

Giaquinto, Marcus.  Hilbert's philosophy of mathematics.  British
J. Philos. Sci. 34 (1983), no. 2, 119–132

Giaquinto claims the following:

(4) While Hilbert's programme was fruitful and, at the time,
plausible the resuscitation of formalism by Robinson and Cohen
(following Cohen's proof of the independence of the Continuum
Hypothesis) is untenable and barren.

Giaquinto bases himself on the following passage from Robinson
(Formalism 64):

"I cannot see at this time how a form of reasoning which attempts to
escape the consequences of Gödel's second theorem (such as Gentzen's
consistency proof or any other consistency proof for Arithmetic) can
remain strictly finitistic and hence interpreted"

and goes on to claim that

"the formalist foundational programme is irredeemable."

Giaquinto's comments date from the period when Reverse Mathematics
was only gathering steam, and he may not have been aware of these
contemporary developments.  Furthermore, Artemov's result seems to
prove Giaquinto wrong, since it precisely provides a possible way of
escaping the consequences of Goedel's second theorem.
Do these developments undermine Giaquinto's conclusion?
Note 1. It is unhelpful to call people names, as name-calling can
boomerang. As far as the substantive issue is concerned, there are two
distinct conceptions of consistency of PA: (1) following Hilbert and
formalized by Artemov as CON^S(PA), and (2) as formalized by Goedel,
usually denoted CON(PA). Formalisation (2) is strictly stronger than
(1). Artemov showed that (1) can be proved within PA itself, though
(2) cannot.  Some users have raised the question of how "novel"
Artemov's work is, but this is a side issue as far as the substantive
discussion is concerned. Denying that (1) is a possible formalisation
of consistency is also a form of denialism.
Note 2. The issue is not whether Formalism is a viable philosophical approach,
but rather whether Giaquinto's argument establishes his claim that it
isn't.  Since Giaquinto's claim is based on an application of Goedel's
second incompleteness theorem and there is now an approach that
overcomes this hurdle, wouldn't that refute Giaquinto's argument?  As
far as "novelty" is concerned, see my previous comment (in sum, it is
neither here nor there).
Note 3. Robinson possessed a detailed philosophy of mathematics that he arrived at empirically.  Robinson wrote: "I do not dispose of a general philosophical creed which, among other things, would determine also my Philosophy of Mathematics."  Thus, the absence of an a priori "creed" is what freed Robinson to develop his philosophy of mathematics freely and unhindered.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Unless Giaquinto was given to telegraphic prose, I assume "plausible" should be "it is plausible that". That's barely a "claim"; it's closer to a suggestion for further consideration.

@keshlam, there is a problem with parsing here.  I suggest you try the following alternative punctuation that makes the meaning clearer: "While Hilbert's programme was fruitful and at the time plausible, the resuscitation of formalism by Robinson and Cohen (following Cohen's proof of the independence of the Continuum Hypothesis) is untenable and barren."  Actually the reason Giaquinto uses the term barren against these mathematicians is because Cohen in an earlier article claimed that philosophical discussions are "barren".  It was a quid pro quo :-)  More precisely, "tit for tat".

I think Giaquinto makes a subtle fallacy by assuming incompleteness is a mark against formalism exclusively. In a certain sense, incompleteness is really just the halting problem in disguise. The halting problem can be expressed in the language of arithmetic, and so unless we can solve the halting problem, then we cannot decide all arithmetical truths. All evidence points to this being physically impossible.
More strongly, due to Post's theorem, we would need to decide the halting problem of every finite turing jump before we can completely decide arithmetic. There is good reason to suspect this to be impossible, so if formalism is "irredeemable" due to incompleteness, then it would seem all of human thought about arithmetic is irredeemable.

To elaborate, Godel assumed that for a formal system to be used by humans, it must have decidable proof verification. However, once we are restricted to decidable proof verification, it almost immediately follows that the set of theorems are recursively enumerable, and therefore cannot decide the halting problem. Naively this would seem to be a mark against formalism, but in reality the halting problem has proven prohibitively difficult for humans to solve. There is good reason to suspect that this will forever be the case.
All currently existing physical theories can be restricted to computable analysis without any loss of descriptive power. Computable analysis has most of the features of Real analysis, but fails to satisfy the topological completeness axiom, since all limits must be computable. However, any computable sequence which converges effectively (i.e. faster than at least one computable sequence) will actually have a computable limit. As far as I can tell, there are no instances in modern Physics where this fails. Einstein's equations for relativity are computable. Schrodinger's wave equation is computable. The observable universe contains only a finite amount of information, so if it's really running on computable laws of physics, then it is certainly computable (in the abstract mathematical sense).
Unless there's some hypercomputational law of physics we haven't discovered yet, no physical system will ever solve the halting problem, which includes humanity. Certainly, no physical system could be capable of deciding all arithmetical truths, not even in principle. Even if we permit ourselves to make arbitrary guesses, and revise our beliefs upon revelation of new information, the set of eventually-stable beliefs could achieve at most the first or second turing jump. The halting problem being undecidable by humans might even be philosophically necessary: if humans can't verify the correctness of an oracle to the halting problem, then we can't really say we "know" that it's correct. Even if there were some hypercomputational law of physics, without some underlying mechanism guaranteeing correctness, it would appear to us to be indistinguishable from randomness.

In the comments, you said you didn't know of a concrete example of a purely arithmetic statement without an intuitively preferred truth value. Following my descriptions above, it should be possible (at least in principle) to construct some extremely complicated statement encoding the behavior of a physical system, and then use that to construct a problem with no obvious solution. A practical example would be something like:

Does there exist a text input to which GPT 5 responds with a valid formal proof of the Poincare conjecture?

Since GPT 5 is a specific computer program, its behavior is arithmetically definable, so the above question corresponds to a well-defined arithmetical sentence. If we had access to GPT's source code (and someone does), we could easily construct the desired arithmetical statement without much trouble. Of course, the arithmetic statement which formalizes the above would be unbelievably large, but only about as large as GPT itself, which is not so large that we couldn't store it in a computer that actually exists. The poincare conjecture was proven a while back, so it seems plausible that GPT might be able to recite a proof if you explained it in detail... But can it actually? I have no clue.
That said, it's actually quite easy to construct statements with no intuitively preferred truth value. I'll give a couple abstract examples.

Does the Riemann Hypothesis admit a formal proof (or disproof) in first-order Peano Arithmetic?

The above is interesting, since although RH is intuitively preferred as being "true", the question of whether it's provable over PA specifically is completely unintuitive. PA is just barely on the edge of what we'd expect to be able to solve this type of problem. If you think the answer is intuitively "yes", consider restricting the induction axiom schema to only allow induction by Σn properties, for some finite n of your choosing. If any, what is the smallest n for which that restricted system decides the Riemann Hypothesis? Or, if you want a yes/no question: is the smallest such n even?

are supercompact cardinals consistent over ZFC?

Note the above is a purely arithmetical statement about the consistency of a set of axioms. Whether a supercompact cardinal actually exists is nonarithmetical, but the consistency of its existence is entirely arithmetical. I personally have no intuition whatsoever on the question. You could also replace "supercompact" with some other large-cardinal property, depending on your own personal level of plausibility.

First, this is a very enlightening answer! Thank you. A quibble: yes, in principle any (finite?) computer program is nicely "definable", in various senses... but/and if the state can further evolve due to (kinda-random, unrestricted additional inputs), ... is there a good notion of (arithmetically, etc.) definable? E.g., supposedly all responses to all inputs are determined in advance? I am only an amateur here...

@paulgarrett There is some subtlety there, yes, but it doesn't apply in this case. A program which is sensitive to inputs can in principle produce uncomputable behavior, but only if its inputs are themselves uncomputable. Likewise if you swap "uncomputable" with "undefinable (arithmetically)". Every finite sequence is computable trivially, so this subtlety is only relevant when a program runs forever and accepts infinitely many inputs. That doesn't apply to my example with GPT, since if it produces a certain output then it would have produced that output with a finite input.

Ah, good, thanks. :)

Re your "but in reality the halting problem has proven prohibitively difficult for humans to solve. There is good reason to suspect that this will forever be the case", isn't the famous Godel sentence in the first incompleteness theorem assuming Con(PA) can be known by human to be true in the meta due to its very construction, without an oracle or Turing jump? Platonists such as Godel has no issue about the truth of such sentences and truth is semantically defined in the meta anyway per Tarski. Also, there're some theories which are incomputable such as the famous Kolmogorov complexity...

Additionally your metaphoric examples trying to use PA to express GPT-5 or RH related statements seem problematic, which is not unlike using PA to express the Liar sentence, since we're not sure if PA has the expressive capacity for GPT-5 or RH stuffs semantically, though we know PA can represent its own proof per Godel coding and implement general recursion. Otherwise, there's no need for natural languages, PA is enough to express every natural human-understandable statement...

@DoubleKnot The Godel sentence of a theory T is logically equivalent to Con(T), and belief in Con(T) just means our metatheory is stronger than T. We might argue that we ought to believe our metatheory is consistent, but we'll never actually reach that belief. In the context of humans, the correct reading of Godel might be that the set of things we believe is larger than the set of things we know we believe. As soon as we identify a particular theory T we know we believe, we'll immediately infer Con(T), which is a new belief not contained by T (unless T is inconsistent).

@DoubleKnot All my examples are arithmetically definable and there are no metaphors. RH is known to be equivalent to a Σ1 arithmetical sentence, GPT-5 is just an ordinary computer program, PA is known to be able to reason about computer programs, and there's a program which verifies whether a given text string is a formal PA proof. We don't need to understand GPT's natural language, we only check if it produces a valid formal proof. This is all very complicated, but it's common knowledge among proof theorists: we are sure that PA has the expressive capacity for my examples.

@DoubleKnot I'd be more than happy to elaborate on the subtleties of any of these subjects, if you ping me in chat. If not, rest assured that I am a subject expert who has "done their homework". I'm very certain about the mathematical components of my answer.

Jade, thanks, very interesting.  As far as statements without a preferred truth value, it would be even better to have one with established independence.  Are there any (of course beyond CH)?

Your GPT-5/RH examples aim to offer some PA-statements without a preferred truth value, along with your computable analysis expo as extension of real analysis. Truth is semantic and not first class citizen in a formal system especially for formalists anyway, so any such arithmetic statement is simply undecidable statement such as the classic Godel sentence or Con(PA) statements. PA cannot express the Liar sentence due to PA's truth-undefinability per Tarski, so any statement involving truth predicate you have to be careful. Also incomputable K-complexity is related to physics via entropy...

Or just using quantifier complexity via arithmetic hierarchy to offer much simpler example PA statements without preferred truth value, if your focus is complexity instead of computability? Finally your answer seems a general critique of all epistemologies of math while (mechanistic) Platonism could be viewed as ontology beyond epistemology such as Fictionalism, Nominalism, and (positivistic) Formalism and Constructivism, but OP is mainly interested in Hilbert's finitistic meta-math foundation Formalism resurrection in light of contemporary progress especially the linked Artemov's result...

@MikhailKatz For practical reasons, it's difficult to give an example which is known to be independent while also having no preferred truth value. For example, if a Σ1 statement is independent over PA, then it's actually just true (because a false Σ1 statement is provably false). This applies to RH, since RH is equivalent to a  Σ1 statement. The RH might be independent, but if we could prove it's independent then we'd immediately know it's true.

@DoubleKnot Yes, in a sense my answer is a critique of all mathematical ontologies, as unknowability is an inherent feature of mathematics. However, it doubles as a pointed refutation of Giaquinto: I am accusing him of special pleading against Formalism. Formalism is no more or less guilty of incompleteness than any other ontology. For the record, I do not personally subscribe to formalism; I just think Giaquinto's criticism is unfair.

@JadeVanadium From my reading of Giaquinto, he's not denying human unknowability as an inherent feature of math perhaps as a result of human finite epistemology compared to a possibly infinite Platonic ontology admitting Turing jumps. He's just denying the chance of resurrection of any kind of single complete finitistic meta-math foundation based on clearly and distinctively known Godel's G1/2 and Cohen's CH results, which I don't see any fallacy if not in favor of it...

@JadeVanadium, This is true about Sigma1 statements, but this does not apply for example to the twin prime conjecture, which could in principle be independent.

@MikhailKatz Yes, it's entirely possible, it's just very difficult to know. Knowing independence requires deep intricate knowledge, so the line between "known independent" and "decided" is extremely thin. As far as I can tell, V=L seems to decide every known independent statement except for large cardinal axioms. I feel V=L is intuitively true, but this is controversial and hence subjective. By contrast, large cardinal axioms are specifically designed to be "intuitively true" so long as they're consistent. If we knew independence then we'd probably just think they're true.

Recently I came across an interesting candidate that would go against assuming all cardinals beyond ZFC.  A colleague in current work showed that establishing de Finetti's theorem in full generality requires a hypothesis that goes against the existence of a certain cardinal, and is tied to the non-existence of non-Radon measures.  Also there is a text by Hamkins that "infinite ascent" doesn't always work.

We have to disentangle the discussion about the "foundational" issues from the traditional philosophical discussions.
I mean that the Four schools of the 1920s were relevant because they started research programs in the foundations that are, in various ways, still alive and gave us new insights.
Example: we can have no interest in reading Brouwer's quite puzzling philosophical statements but Constructive Mathematics is a mathematical discipline on its own and it is alive and well.
The same for realism: Penelope Maddy books about the axioms of set theory are relevant.
Regarding Hilbert, my opinion is that what is relevant was not so much Formalism but Hilbert's program: it has been sunk by Godel's Theorem... and the day after re-started with Gentzen's proof. Also in this case Proof Theory and Reverse mathematics are mathematical disciplines on their own that are alive and well. They are "long-term" fruits of Hilbert's school.
More specifically regarding Hilbert, that never wrote a treatise called "Philosophy of Mathematics, we can see at least two more (wrt Giaquinto 1983 paper) recent contributes:

Curtis Franks, The Autonomy of Mathematical Knowledge: Hilbert's Program Revisited (Cambridge University Press, 2009), and

Alan Weir, Truth Through Proof: A Formalist Foundation for Mathematics (Oxford UP, 2010).


As a provisional conclusion, regarding my point of view wrt the interplay of "philosophy of..." and "foundations of..", I'll suggest the final comment from Solomon Feferman's review of Franks' book:

The autonomy of mathematical knowledge in practice is a fact: mathematicians
have no need of a book like this to convince them that philosophers have nothing to tell them about what ought and ought not to count as mathematics. And they do not question its carrying an apparent body of truths within and ⎯far and wide⎯ outside of mathematics. But that will not and should not stop philosophers from asking:
“Knowledge of what? And by what means?” whether or not any mathematicians are
listening.


Regarding more specifically Giaquinto's 1983 paper -maybe a preliminary part of the much later The Search For Certainty (2002): see the discussion of Hilbert's Finitism in chapter 3- my first comment regards teh point of view: a "philosophical" assessment of Hilbert's Philosophy of Mathematics (see my concern above) that "seems to have been refuted as decisively as any
philosophical view can be, there is a tendency to see his formalist
programme and its philosophical basis as a relatively unimportant cul-de-sac in the history of the philosophy of mathematics."
Formalist programme=Hilbert's program=Philosophy of Mathematics? Maybe this equation is not 100% correct.
It "has refuted as decisively as any philosophical view can be". Agreed: philosophy is not science and it is difficult to imagine a refutation.
Personally, I agree with the initial assessment: "Hilbert's firm belief prior to 1931 in the achievability of his programme was not unreasonable, [and] Hilbert's programme was fruitful and, at the time, plausible".
Wrt the critique to Robinson, my two concerns are:
(i) Giaquinto's paper dates 1984: 40 years are too much if comapred to the development of scientific research: see reverse and constructive mathematics, while it is only the blink of an eye wrt to good old Plato.
(ii) Giaquinto refers to Robinson's Formalism 64 [60 years ago!] but Robinson is quite explicit [pages 229-231]:

As the title indicates my position is, basically, close to that of Hilbert and his school. I have added the year, 64, not only because it is now known that Hilbert's program is doomed to failure but also because the present picture in the foundations of Mathematics has been affected by important developments in several other directions. [...] In choosing my position, ny approach ahs been empirical. That is to say, I have tried to take into account all the evidence available to me that may have bearing on the subject, including both basic thinking abd "technical" results in Logic and Mathematics. I do not dispose of a general philosophical creed which, among other things, would determine also my Philosophy of Mathematics. [...] My position concerning the foundations of Mathematics is based on the following two main points: (i) Infinite totalities do not exist in any sense of the word. More precisely, any mention of infinite totalities is, literally,meaningless. (ii) Nevertheless, we should continue the business of Mathematics "as usual" [...] I must regard a theory which refers to an infinite totality as meaningless in the sense that its terms and sentences cannot possess the direct interpretation in an actual structure [...]".

Thus, Robinson adopts Hilbert's Formalism with rejection of actual infinity, but rejects the "failed" Hilbert's Porgram.
Robinson was the celebrated author of Introduction to Model Theory and the Metamathematics of Algebra (North Holland, 1963). See page 13:

Let S be the set of relative symbols of K [the set of sentences of a language L]. [...] In order to prove the theorem for K of arbitrary infinite cardinal [emphasis mine] (countable or non-countable)...

"Meaningless" infinities are part of working mathematician's business "as usual".

In conclusion, my point of view is that Hilbert's Finitism has been refuted by Godel's Theorem but Hilbert's Program restarted with new tools and approaches.
Giaquinto's article is valuable: we can disagree with the Conclusion, but saying that "it has been refuted" makes little sense, being an historical paper.
And also to say that Robinson 1964 position was , in 1984, "untenable" can be misleading: it was the well-known formalism.

(1) As you point out, some mathematicians feel that Artemov's work is "not particularly novel".  However, as mentioned in my question, this is a separate issue from the one dealt in the question, namely the existence of an alternative formalisation of the consistency of PA.  Even if it is "not particularly novel" as claimed by the critics, Artemov's work points to a gap in Giaquinto's argument, based wholecloth on Goedel's second incompleteness theorem and Giaquinto's interpretation thereof.

(2) Hilbert's formalism and Hilbert's program are not disjoint topics.  Consider, for example, Simpson's impressive list of results in analysis and elsewhere which are equivalent to the axiom WKL0 (over RCA0).  This means that a large (and certainly not "barren") part of classical analysis is consistent if and only if a finitist system such as PRA is consistent.  Such a result is convincing to a Formalist but probably not to a finitist (since it does not imply that such analysis results are finitistic; only finitistically reducible).

Thus, as far as a substantial part of analysis is concerned, Formalism does provide a satisfactory account, pointing to another weakness in Giaquinto's argumentation.

(3) Robinson did not have a specific philosophical creed that would have predetermined his philosophy of mathematics; rather, he arrived at his philosophical position in an empirical fashion, by eliminating philosophical positions he found untenable.  This includes the specific technical details of eliminating nominalism, platonism, constructivism, and logical positivism.

(4) Robinson does not reject actual infinity as a mathematical tool.  He only rejects the idea that actual infinity has a referent in either the physical or any putative platonic realm.  Since he accepts the use of actual infinity in mathematics (as a useful fiction), his position does not "go back to Aristotle".  Thus he was a Formalist on the weekdays, as well.

P.S. You have repeatedly claimed that there is a "consensus" among
experts with regard to Artemov's work.  Note however that the real
logic heavyweights at MO have not expressed themselves at that
question.  They are Bauer, Blass, Hamkins, and Jerabek.  I take this
as significant evidence toward the claim that in fact there is no
consenus among experts.

@MikhailKatz - You are saying that this answer is seriously misleading because it misinterprets some of the positions - correct? If so, did you therefore also vote to Delete the answer (unless, perhaps, the answer is updated)?

@MauroALLEGRANZA No, definitely not. I actually upvoted the answer, since even though I don't fully agree, I think it brings up valid points! My question was a question of clarification. I was curious why anyone (he - I don't know) would go to such rather extreme measures.

@MauroALLEGRANZA - np :)
